# PySide's QTest not checking box

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyside

Here is my code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtTest
import sys

application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
assert not checkbox.isChecked()
QtTest.QTest.mouseClick(checkbox, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
assert checkbox.isChecked()
```

I expected the checkbox to become checked after the simulated mouse click. But it doesn't. I'm on Mac OS X, Python 2.7 with a freshly brew installed PySide.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a linux box.

Comment: I *can* reproduce this on windows 8, Python 2.7, PySide 1.1.2

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem.  In my case the default click position was incorrect.  The documentation states that the default position is the center of the widget.

```
>>> print checkbox.rect()
PySide.QtCore.QRect(0,0,640,480)
```

All the other examples use push buttons which, can be set to any size, so it will fill the entire available space.  The checkbox, however, cannot be resized.
Since I can't actually see the checkbox, I assumed that it was horizontally on the left and vertically in the middle.

```
>>> QTest.mouseClick(checkbox, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, pos=QtCore.QPoint(2,checkbox.height()/2)
>>> print checkbox.isChecked()
True
```