# How to test QRadioButton with QtBot?

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to check QRadioButton with QtBot but it even can`t change` isChecked` state.

```
type(default_button)
>> <class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton'>
default_button.isChecked()
>> False
qtbot.mouseClick(default_button, Qt.LeftButton)
default_button.isChecked()
>> False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19418125

Comment: is a button checked or clicked? checked is a checkbox is one thinks logical...